# Different displays between Matlab command window and Matlab gui platform of the same command

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I want to connect a push button to a hyperlink in my ***MATLAB GUI***. I'm using the following command

```
disp('This is a link to <a href="https://www.google.gr/"> Google </a>.')
```

When i run it inside Matlab it displays this in the command window:

```
This is a link to Google.
```

Which is what i want, **but** when i run the gui app it displays the following

```
This is a link to <a href="https://www.google.gr/"> Google </a>.
```

Does anyone know what to do so that my gui displays the same as Matlab command window?

Comment: [Answered](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hyperlink-text-labels) by *Yair Altman* in his blog.

Comment: I've already saw this and have applied it, but i wanted something more simple like the one i'm trying. However, thank you for your time!